# Serialize a bean to json string using com.fasterxml.jackson with the following format

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonserializer, fasterxml

In general, jackson is serialize beans to standard json format, for example, the following class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    // getter/setter
}
```

will serialize to following json:

```
{
  "name" : "test1111",
  "age" : 18
}
```

but i want to get the format like this(non-standard):

```
{
  name : test1111,
  age : 18
}
```

that is to say, i didn't want to output the double-quote despite of the type.
Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not valid JSON and therefore you cannot use Jackson to generate it.

If you want, you can use Jackson to generate a `String` value of

```
{
  "name" : "test1111",
  "age" : 18
}
```

and then manually remove the quotes.